Codeigniter 4 validation return empty validated array
I need help to figure out how validation works in Codeigniter 4.
I can succesfully send a form with POST data but after validation I get an empty array.
Following the CI userguide I set the following controller:
public function collection()
{

    if ( $this->request->is('post')) {
        $rules = [
            'record'    => 'alpha_numeric_punct',
            'record_id' => 'is_natural_no_zero',
            'region'    => 'is_natural_no_zero',
        ];

        $data = $this->request->getPost(array_keys($rules));

        if (! $this->validateData($data, $rules)) {
            $errors = $this->validator->getErrors();
        }
        
        $validData = $this->validator->getValidated();

        $data['validated'] = $validData;
        $data['errors'] = $errors;
    }
}

The form in view page succesfully send post data using a form...the weird things is: checking the 'validated' and 'errors' data with a print_r command in view I can see the error...but $validData is an empty array.
Here you are the message in view when I submit a form without data in region and data in record_id nad record filed:
Array ( [region] => Il campo "region" deve contenere solo caratteri numerici e deve essere maggiore di zero. )

Array ( )

What am I doing wrong? thanks a lot for any feedback.

I think getValidated only holds data if the validation was successful aka no errors were thrown.

Thanks a lot for your feedback and hint Simon. U are right...silly me!
